# Association with JavaScript without using a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to JavaScript and NodeJS and Express. Actually, I have imported an accounts array from an account model and I want to create a new transaction.

However, I failing to get the actual account number from the accounts array and use it in my new transaction object. When I try to access it I'm getting the undefined. I would appreaciate your help.

Thank you.

**My account model.**

```
export default []
```

**My accounts controller**

```
import accounts from '../models/account'; 

class Account{
  static createAccount(req, res){

        let m = moment(); 
        let real_date = m.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a');

        const newAccount = {

            created_on: real_date,
            account_number: accounts.length + 1, 
            owner: req.body.owner, 
            type: req.body.type, 
            status: req.body.status, 
            balance: parseFloat(req.body.balance)

        }

        accounts.push(newAccount); 
        res.status(201).send({
            status: 201, 
            data: newAccount
        })

    }
}
```

**Transaction Model**

```
export default []
```

**Transactions controller**

```
import accounts from '../models/account/'
class Transaction {

    static debitAccount(req, res) {


        let m = moment();
        const created_on = m.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a');

        const {
            amount,
            old_balance,
            transaction_type,
            cashier
        } = req.body;

        let x, y, sum;
        x = amount
        y = old_balance;
        sum = parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y);


        accounts.forEach((account) => {
           const  account_id = account.account_number;
        });


        const newDebit = {
            created_on: created_on,
            transaction_id: transactions.length + 1,
            account_number: account_id,
            cashier: parseInt(cashier),
            transaction_type: transaction_type,
            old_balance: parseFloat(old_balance),
            amount: parseFloat(amount),
            new_balance: sum
        }

        console.log('New Debit', newDebit);
        transactions.push(newDebit);
        res.status(201).send({
            status: 201,
            message: 'Amount successfully debited!',
            data: newDebit
        })
    }
```

**N.B:** As you may see, I used account_number in place of id.

Comment: There isn't enough here to make a good answer. What does `account` look like and what do you expect the `forEach` to do -- right now it's going through all the account numbers and assigning one after the other to the same variable.

Comment: what is `accounts`? I can see only 2 ways for `account_id` to be `undefined` here: either `accounts` is empty, or the last element in `accounts` has no `account_number` property. (Note also that what you are doing here will always result in `account_id` holding the `account_number` of the last element in the `accounts` array, which I would guess isn't what you want.)

Comment: Is `account_id` declared outside the scope of the `forEach` loop?  If you are declaring it within that loop you won't be able to access the value outside of it.  Also, you will be updating the `account_id` for every single `account` in your `accounts` list before you ever create a `newDebit` object.  If you want a `newDebit` object for each account you'll need to change up your logic.

Comment: *"want to create a new transaction"* ... explain in more detail what this transaction is supposed to do. Broken code often isn't a good substitute for  detailed explanation of the issue although the code is also needed to assist with debugging the issue

Comment: Hi @MarkMeyer and others, I have updated the question to help with debugging. Thank you again.!